# quartz + mysql - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler

I have an issue for `Lock wait timeout exceeded` from quartz + mysql + Tomcat7. When I use one server for dev and qa, the issue that I am facing didn't come up, but I started seeing an issue in the production env (with 2 servers) after the deployment.

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'trigger1355274000000' for '1355274000000' job:Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction] 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1270) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggerFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2961) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$38.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2871) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3788) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggerFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2865) 
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:319) 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction 
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2046) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1964) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1949) 
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102) 
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.updateTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1295) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1256)
```

This is my quartz config.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = ApplicationDemoScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread=true
org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=180000

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=qzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL=select LOCK_NAME from QRTZ_LOCKS where LOCK_NAME=?
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

org.quartz.scheduler.dbFailureRetryInterval=15000


org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.jndiURL=java:comp/env/jdbc/appDemoJndi
```

And this data source is referencing the data source configured in the Tomcat.

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/appDemoJndi" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="testuser" password="test_pswd"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testuser"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          initialSize="20" maxWait="5000"
          maxActive="40" maxIdle="5"
         testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          defaultAutoCommit="false"
          maxOpenPreparedStatements="20" 
          validationQuery="select 1"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
```

I am not relying on any hibernate or anything. I am not quite sure if this error is related to any quartz configuration or MYSQL configuration.

Is there anybody who has had the same issue and resolved it?  Please help...

Thanks.

Comment: Check in mysql that the pending lock comes from mysql. Do you have anything else accessing those tables that could cause the lock? Do you have strange things in QRTZ_LOCKS ?

Comment: This code is used only in the backend area. So with my understanding, i don't think that this table is used from other areas. I am wondering if it is because of other servers that have same configuration. In the LOCK table, I see CALENDAR_LOCK, JOB_ACCESS, MISFIRE_ACCESS, STATE_ACCESS, TRIGGER_ACCESS.

Comment: did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue ended up increasing the transaction lock
[mysqld]
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120